# How to change that 'Netlify' branding shown in the picture?

Tags: netlify

[Netlify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r05dL.jpg)
How to change that 'Netlify' branding shown in the picture?
I tried but couldn't get to solve.

Previously i have changed the Favicon, title and meta description too. But I'm literally stuck with this branding, please help!

Comment: This question is really more about Google/SEO than about Netlify. I don't know any specific, but I can tell you that this is not a "live-updating" thing. You will need to wait for at least the next time Google indexes your page for any change that you did to become visible on the result page (and if your page is not a multi-million-hits-per-day top site, then potentially even more often as you might not be in the live-updating index, but in one of the auxilliary indices that get updates as batch jobs, assuming this distinction still exists, by knowledge in that area is already a bit dated).